# Find cell values that are x% similar in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Essentially I have a bunch of data in a Google sheet from a Google form asking people what video games they play. I have results like "CSGO" and "CS:GO" as well as "Kovaak 2.0" and "KovaaK". I'd like to be able to find similarities like (within a certain %) these and turn one into the other so they are uniform.

**E.g.**

```
Minecraft
osu!
Fortnite
CS:GO
Aim Lab
CSGO
```

**Would Return:**

```
Minecraft
osu!
Fortnite
CS:GO
Aim Lab
CS:GO
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to create a "normalized" list of game names where you have removed punctuation like `-`, `!`, `.` and `&`, spaces, capitalization and "null" words such as `the`, `a` and `and`.

To match the free-form game names in form responses to the list, normalize a game name and then use `match()` to check if it is in the list.

The normalization can be done with spreadsheet functions such as `lower()`, `trim()` and `regexreplace()`, and should give you quite good, but not perfect, results.

To do this properly, you would need to use fuzzy matching, which is much more involved and requires an add-on or script. See [Approximate string matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching). To find an add-on to do this, search the [Google Workspace Marketplace](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/search/fuzzy).

Comment: See the [Formulas by Top Contributors](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/formulas_by_top_contributors/515924842729) Add-on for the [Levenshtein distance formula](https://sites.google.com/view/madebytopcontributors/custom-formulas/levenshtein) we've made available. Not easy to look for if not explicitly mentioned. Disclaimer: created and maintain the Addon